# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**models.py**

```
class answers(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.ForeignKey(Task)
    answer = models.URLField()
    ANSWER_CHOICES = (
        ('F', 'Declined'),
        ('T', 'Accepted'),
    )
    accept_answer = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ANSWER_CHOICES, default='f')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer
```

**views.py**

```
def full_task(request, id):
    task = Task.objects.get(id = id)
    instance = get_object_or_404(answers, title=task.title)
    form = AnswerForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'task': task,
    }

    **forms.py**
from django import forms
from .models import answers

class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    answer = forms.URLField()
    class Meta:
        model = answers
        fields = [
            "answer"    
        ]
```

**TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\website\user_profile\views.py" in full_task
  75.     instance = get_object_or_404(answers, title=task.title)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in get_object_or_404
  85.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  376.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  796.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  814.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1183.             condition = lookup_class(lhs, value)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  19.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  100.                 self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "C:\Users\rohit\Desktop\asad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  946.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /tasks/1/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

i have used title as foreign key of Task model. and when i am using query like 
`get_object_or_404(answers, title=task.title)` and `Task.objects.get(title=task.title)` it is giving me this traceback. well i don't know how to remove this error . and one thing i cant understand that the title is a foreign field then how can i get data from diffrent using this foreign key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the `task` instance, not `task.title`:

```
instance = get_object_or_404(answers, title=task)
```

`task.title` is a Unicode string, but the `answers.title` field is a foreign key. You could also pass in the `Task.id` field (assuming that that is the primary key field for that type).

Comment: `NOT NULL constraint failed: answers_answers.title_id` now it is giving me this error when i submit the input.

Comment: @RohitChopra: then `Task.objects.get()` returned `None`. Perhaps you want to use `get_object_or_404(Task, id=id)` instead of `Task.objects.get(id=id)`?

Comment: @RohitChopra: the error means you set `answers.title` to NULL (`None` in Python code) in the form.

Comment: i used `print(task)` output is `abc`

Comment: Right, but how did you connect that to the `answers` object your form is creating?

Comment: @RohitChopra: at any rate, that's a *new problem*, one that probably requires a new question where you show what `AnswerForm` does. I can't help you with that *here on this question*.

Comment: i have added `forms.py` check it out. and tried to use print(form) in my view form is working properly.

Comment: @RohitChopra: please don't keep changing the question; the original problem has been solved. Focus on *one problem at a time*.